# How do I wait for successful connection using DDP in meteor (server -> server)

Tags: meteor, ddp

Continuing the discussion from DDP: [how do I wait for a connection?](https://forums.meteor.com/t/ddp-how-do-i-wait-for-a-connection/7658/3):

Based on the thread above, we an leverage `Tracker.autorun` to wait and confirm for a successful connection between a client and meteor server.

I would like to do the same on a server : server connection

Basically, I have a meteor server (server1), that will need to “test” and see if another meteor server (server2) is available.

Each time I run `DDP.connect(remoteUrl).status()` within server1’s meteor method, it always says “connection”. I know it connects in the next second or two, but I’m unable to wait for checking the connection success flag.

How do i do this on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of reactivity doesn't exist in this form on the server, so something like the Tracker is not an option. Fortunately though there is the [`onReconnect` callback](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-onReconnect) you can use. You can steal the [required logic from my `meteor-serversync` package](https://github.com/chfritz/meteor-serversync/blob/master/serversync.js#L32-L41):

```js
const connection = DDP.connect(URL);
connection.onReconnect = function() {
  console.log("(re)connected");
  if (!initialized) {
    options.onConnect && options.onConnect();
  }
};
```

Comment: Stolen, thanks! :)

Comment: A continuation question.. Is there a way to run this in a loop? I have an array of URLS to check for connectivity. And then update a db record based on the outcome. Something doesn't seem to work right when I put the above code in a loop. I have a feeling the responses are not coming in the same order as it was sent.

Comment: It should be possible, but I'd need to see your code to tell why it might be failing. Can you open a new question?